# Which js to include for google maps place search

Tags: google-maps

I have included js file like

which is specific to places i believe. So if i want to work with drawing api i need to include

```
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>
```

Is there a way i can include as a generic one. I tried to include like

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY?</script>
```

but i get error like

```
Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
```

I'm a bit confused here as to how to solve this.

Comment: I believe you'll need to implement `callback=initMap` in some other way if you remove it from the url.  See the documentation here:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HTML5

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation on [including libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries):

> To request multiple libraries, separate them with a comma:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=YOUR_API_KEY">
> </script>
> ```

If you want to include the drawing library **and** the places library, you need to do this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing,places&callback=initMap"
     async defer></script>
```

(assuming you have an `initMap` function that initializes everything that depends on the Google Maps Javascript API v3)